# Mysql collation PHP charset

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, collation

I'm having kind of a problem with mySQL collation.
My mySQL collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
My pages have .
When I send this text "São Paulo" to mySQL it stores "SÃ£o Paulo" or if I send "Conceição" it stores "ConceiÃ§Ã£o".
It display correctly in my page "São Paulo" and "Conceção" with or without htmlentities().
When I do a search for "São Paulo" it brings the correct records.

Why does it store those strange characters? Is there a way they can match?
I've tried changing the mySQL collation to utf8_unicode_ci, utf8_general_ci, latin1_swedish_ci, latin1_bin but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What is your db connection charset? Paste code.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: I use this to connect, don't specify the connection charset.
$this->conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

Comment: That's called Mojibake.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored